# Set shell's working directory to the current file opened in vim

Tags: bash, vim, cygwin, working-directory

I am using Windows gVim and I am trying to invoke commands to run on cygwin's bash. It is working, but the working directory is set to $HOME every time. Would it possible to set to the current file's directory?

I have the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
set shell=C:/cygwin/bin/bash
set shellcmdflag=--login\ -c
set shellxquote=\"
```

I have the following lines in my `.profile`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `--login` does that; remove that argument and the shell will be opened in GVIM's current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the current file's directory to external commands like this:

```
:!ls %:p:h
```

See `:h filename-modifiers` and possibly `:h shellescape()`.